# Calculating Percentiles in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, field-calculator, statistics, numpy

I have a large polygon dataset (26,000) records with numerous attributes columns.  I wish to calculate the percentile rank of each attribute.  Say I have population_density in an attribute, is there a simple formula to assign a rank in another attribute field on the percentile score of the value in the first attribute column (pop density)?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this using arcpy in conjunction with numpy:

```py
import arcpy
import numpy as np

input = "c:/data/usa.gdb/USA/counties"
arr = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(input, ('population_density'))

##to create 3 rank for example
p1 = np.percentile(arr, 33)  # rank = 0
p2 = np.percentile(arr, 67)  # rank = 1
p3 = np.percentile(arr, 100)  # rank = 2

#use cursor to update the new rank field
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(input , ['population_density','PerRank']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] < p1:
            row[1] = 0  #rank 0
        elif p1 <= row[0] and row[0] < p2:
             row[1] = 1
        else:
             row[1] = 2

        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Just modify the code to adapt to your data and change the number of ranks as needed.

Comment: And in case the OP is unfamiliar with `arcpy`, this code can be entered in the Python window in ArcMap, or saved as a standalone script. It won't work with the Field Calculator.