# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: arcpy, feature-class, numpy

I am trying to insert a value for different group of percentile eg (0- 10 percentitle) value = 1.

I saw an example over here and went to try it out [How do I Calculate Grouped Percentiles or Batch percentiles in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152621/how-do-i-calculate-grouped-percentiles-or-batch-percentiles-in-arcmap?lq=1)

However, i was thrown this error. I am using ArcGis 10.3.1 for desktop. and the file is Shapefile Feature Class.

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 30, in <module>
File "<string>", line 10, in CalcPercentile
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 3096, in percentile
return _compute_qth_percentile(sorted, q, axis, out)
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 3132, in _compute_qth_percentile
return add.reduce(sorted[indexer]*weights, axis=axis, out=out)/sumval
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

The source code is over here. (using python)

```
 import arcpy
 import numpy as np
 import os

  #loop through all Shapefile in a folder and call the CalcPercentile method
 def CalcPercentile(inputFeatureClass):
  #to create 3 rank for example
    print inputFeatureClass;
    arr = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(inputFeatureClass, 'NEAR_DIST_')
    p1 = np.percentile(arr, 33)  # rank = 0
    p2 = np.percentile(arr, 67)  # rank = 1
    p3 = np.percentile(arr, 100)  # rank = 2
    #use cursor to update the new rank field
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inputFeatureClass , ['NEAR_DIST_','PerRank1']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
         if row[0] < p1:
             row[1] = 0  #rank 0
         elif p1 <= row[0] and row[0] < p2:
              row[1] = 1
         else:
              row[1] = 2
         cursor.updateRow(row)

workspace = "D:\HDB_accessibility\MergeAllDistance"
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass")
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
 for filename in filenames:
     featureClass = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
     #First add the percentile Rank Field
     #arcpy.AddField_management(featureClass, "PerRank", "DOUBLE")
     CalcPercentile(featureClass)
```

Comment: could be related to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408122/unsupported-operand-types-for-numpy-ndarray-and-numpy-float64) - where the NEAR_DIST_ field may be converted to a long instead of a float?

Answer (score -1):

As [commented by @fluidmotion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173863/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-numpy-ndarray-and-numpy-ndarray/237261#comment260377_173863) it:

> could be related to
>   [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408122/unsupported-operand-types-for-numpy-ndarray-and-numpy-float64]
>   - where the NEAR_DIST_ field may be converted to a long instead of a float?