# Calculating percentiles from timeseries raster data using ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

My question is similar with [Calculating Percentiles in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132534/calculating-percentiles-in-arcmap)
But I would like to calculate the percentile from timeseries raster data.

I have timeseries raster data from 1981 to 2016, its the max of daily rainfall in a year, so its just 1 raster data for 1 year.

The idea is to get the rainfall threshold and rainfall-triggered flood with return period, let say for 10 and 25 year. If my data is in excel format, I used =PERCENTILE(DATARANGE,0.9) for calculating the rainfall threshold for 10 year return period of rainfall-triggered flood.

For each cell in x,y location from 1981 to 2016, I would like to calculate the percentile of i.e 90%.

How to calculate the percentile for each cell from timeseries raster using ArcGIS?